# You tube categories list using Gdata

Tags: iphone, gdata

I am using Gdata to upload video on you tube.

I need to list all categories to user and choose one for the particular video
can we get categories list of you tube  ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get list with this way. Don't know if there is other way too.
We can get categories list in XML format with this link

http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat

Get data with contents of this URL,

```
 NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat"]];
NSData *data=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

You need to parse it and you can get it from @"label" value.

Thanks.